# Copy everything from an open notepad into a spreadsheet using VBA without having to save the notepad

Tags: vba, excel, notepad

There are some great resources to copy and paste a pre-existing notepad's data into an excel spreadsheet using VBA. I have not found anything to help with my issue though... I would like to copy and paste all the data from an open notepad into an excel spreadsheet, but due to the high volume of these notepads, I would like to not save them. Is there a way to do this.

I just need an idea of how to get started all other criteria etc I can work on from there... thanks in advance!

Comment: welcome to SO, what have you tried so far? please show us some code and where you have the problem

Comment: @lbo thanks for your response. I haven't tried anything for this yet... I know how I would select a saved wordpad document, select everything in it and then paste that into a spreadsheet (in vba). My issue is not with the process but whether it is possible to take a wordpad that is not saved and do the same procedure... without the need to save it.

Comment: I think it is most likely possible, but you need to use windows functions since both Excel application and wordpad run under windows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are just asking for ideas, here are a few:

- You can't rely on SendKeys. AppActivate will only take you halfway there and then you're lost
- Instead you will need a few WinAPI calls, primarily FindWindow and SendMessage
- The message you need most is WM_GETTEXT
- If you don't know the exact window title, you will have to find a Hwnd or the exact title

In the title you say Notepad, but in your comments you say Wordpad. The method on how to extract the text differs slightly.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions! I'll try one of these!